# how to do BETWEEN condition in spark 1.6 version

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have tried `between` condition in **spark 1.6 version** but got an error as

> between is not member of string.

`df.filter($"date".between("2015-07-05", "2015-09-02"))`

Answer (score 4):

Either your `df("date")` is a string type or your column date is not inferred as column.
I have replicated your code and it does work on a column `sent` as which is `java.sql.Timestamp`:

```
val test= bigDF.filter($"sent_at".between("2015-07-05", "2015-09-02"))
```

ensure that your col `date` is a valid `df` column, try `df("date")` or `col("date")` and that it is saved as data time type ex:

```
case class Schema(uuid: String, sent_at: java.sql.Timestamp)

val df1 = df.as[Schema]
```

do `df.printSchema(`) to verify the type of date column